# Прервать выполнение кода после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Когда происходит timeout вызывается модальное окно и через 5 секунд происходит выход из сессии. Хочу отменить выход, если пользователь нажмет на кнопку "Отмена" до истечении 5 секунд и timeout сбрасывался. 
Можно ли сделать как-то выход из родительской функции, чтобы setTimeout не срабатывал?

```
function LogoutByTimer()
    {   
    showModal();

    jQuery('#disabledout').click(function(){
        $timeout.cancel(TimeOut_Thread); 
    });
    console.log('Logout'); 
    setTimeout(function(){$window.location.href="/exit.php"} , 5000);   
    }
```

Comment: что за _$timeout.cancel_ используется? если это вдруг ангуляр, зачем использовать jQuery и setTimeout?

Comment: наверно только потому, что я не очень хорошо знаком с англяром и начал небольшой микс творить.. каюсь, так делать нельзя)

Comment: не очень желательно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция setTimeout возвращает числовой идентификатор таймера `timerId`, который можно использовать для отмены действия.

Синтаксис:

```
var timerId = setTimeout(...);
clearTimeout(timerId);
```

В следующем примере мы ставим таймаут, а затем удаляем (передумали). В результате ничего не происходит.

```js
    var timerId = setTimeout(function() { alert(1) }, 1000);
    alert(timerId); // число - идентификатор таймера
    
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    alert(timerId); // всё ещё число, оно не обнуляется после отмены
```

---

> [Документация по setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)
>
> [Оригинал на сайте learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

Comment: если вопрос на самом деле был про ангуляр, то лучше использовать его механизмы

Comment: @Grundy да, согласен. но как можно было понять что это про ангуляр? там ведь просто функция js ?

Comment: например по специфическому `$timeout.cancel` и `$window`

Comment: @Grundy т.е. мой ответ плох?

Comment: сойдет, можно еще добавить ссылку на документацию по `setTimeout`. И не совсем понятно зачем нужен текст после сниппета